# Getting all sites for user with permissions

Tags: 2013, javascript, search, rest, search-api

I'm trying to get all sites for a user on which he has permissions. For this I'm using the search api. In a for-loop from `0` to `totalRows`. This is my request url:

```
https://www.intranet.i/site/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:STS_Web'&selectproperties='Title,URL'&startrow=" + i + "&rowlimit=100"
```

This is working fine for a lot of pages, but some are not returned, any idea why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How were you able to solve this? No answer for this question works for me. I only get a subset of lists. I don't even some Sites for which I am the owner. Strange!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding '&trimduplicates=false' to your query.

```
https://www.intranet.i/site/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:STS_Web'&selectproperties='Title,URL'&startrow=" + i + "&rowlimit=100&trim"
```

Comment: Still doesn't give the desired results? I have some Site Collections where I am the Primary Site Admin, I still don't get those Site Collections in this API call? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
contentclass:STS_Site
```

in your query along with web since the permissions may differ

Comment: Still doesn't return all. Any other solution?