# How to get list of site collections using APP ONLY access token through REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, office-365

I'm looking for a way to get the list of site collections for my O365 Subscriptions. 
Now I have come across various answers to this but NONE of them works for me. I am using Client Credentials Flow to get the access token which means >>> APP Only Token.
I have tried

```
https://{tenantName}-admin.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:sts_site'
```

and I get

```
500 Internal server error
{
  "error": {
    "code": "-1, Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.SearchServiceException",
    "message": {
        "lang": "en-US",
        "value": "An unknown error occurred."
    }
  }
}
```

I have come across the following links

- [Getting all sites for user with permissions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98020/getting-all-sites-for-user-with-permissions)
- [What is the REST endpoint URL to get list of site collections?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113528/what-is-the-rest-endpoint-url-to-get-list-of-site-collections)
- [Powershell to list all sites and subsites in SharePoint Online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101176/powershell-to-list-all-sites-and-subsites-in-sharepoint-online/101263?noredirect=1#comment154171_101263)
- [I want to get list of all site collection available on SharePoint Server 2013 using CSOM or REST API but not server object model](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/137739/i-want-to-get-list-of-all-site-collection-available-on-sharepoint-server-2013-us)
- https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/How-to-get-all-the-tenant-2999c21b
- http://blah.winsmarts.com/2014-4-Get_list_of_site_collections_using_CSOM_in_Office365.aspx

And

- [Server error when accessing Search api via REST](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/120672/server-error-when-accessing-search-api-via-rest)

The last link appeared to be promising and I created the LIST(QueryPropertiesTemplate) as mentioned, but how am I supposed to get the FARM ID? Since this is Sharepoint Online and not on premise.

Any help with this?

Comment: I have found the following to be very helpful for stepping through the process
Accessing Tenant ID for Sharepoint Online etc. http://www.ktskumar.com/2017/01/access-sharepoint-online-using-postman/

Answer (score 1):

Is it not "-admin" in the URL that is your problem.
I tried with my tenant and without admin and got an response.
[image]

Comment: If you have a new question, please use the "Ask Question" button at the top of the page. This section is for answers only, not subsequent questions or discussions. Thank You.