# SPFx get all sites were user has permissions

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, react

is there a way to get all site collections and subsites where the current user has access to? I would like to build a web part in SPFx and in React.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: is there any any way to get the permission for current user to access particular site collections or not using spfx

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the search API searching for sites as mentioned in [this other question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98020/getting-all-sites-for-user-with-permissions).